# jQuery not recognizing tel input type

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

I'm using one of the new input types for telephone number "tel"

```
<input class="phoneUS" id="cphone" name="phone" type="tel" required/>
```

But when I try to select them with jQuery:

```
$('input["tel"]').css('background','red');
```

It doesn't work. So, I try it on the console and I get:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input["tel"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input[type="tel"]').css('background','red');
```

Should be what you're after :) You were very close, you just need to tell jQuery that it is an input type you are looking for.